# INPUT tag without a FORM

Tags: php, forms, button, input

I am creating a button as such

```
<INPUT type='submit' name='name-of-button' value='Submit'>
```

However, this button is NOT enclused in a FORM. In other words, there isn't any form to submit.

That said, when a user clicks on the button, a certain action should start in PHP. For the sake of an example, clicking on Submit will write a value to the database.

Now, I am not sure how to handle the code in PHP. Do I have to put a form around it? I would like to check using something simlar to following PHP?

```
if (isset('name-of-button')) {
    // Do something, such as writing to the db
}
```

I know the above code is incorrect. Because we have to submit the form, and use the post action as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['name-of-button'])) {
    // Do something, such as writing to the db
}
```

But again, I do not like to use a form if possible. PLEASE HELP :)

Please not that I do not want to use JavaScript either, pure PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use a form? Why make things more difficult for yourself?

Comment: It is not valid HTML to have an INPUT not in a FORM, and you should not expect browsers to play nice.

Comment: Alternative (could be easily googled): you can style an ordinary link to look like a button with CSS.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - In HTML5 it is.

Comment: You cant call a php function from a webpage without either javascript ajax call or form submit.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - What do you mean by associated with a form? No form element at all needs to exist on the page in HTML when using an input element. I agree with you it's bad practice, however it is valid.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  The button without a form is not a bad priactice. It was designed for situations where you do not need a form and all you need is a button, and where you can handle your code via AJAX.

Comment: @j08691 Please read my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks everyone for your replies.

Just to make sure the post is complete and to help others:

As stated by some of your answers, to call a PHP function, I must either use form submit, use AJAX, or use a link. Therefore, for me, I will choose the easiest solution, which is use a form.

That said, according to the standard in HTML, you can use INPUT tags without a form. I think that was done so as to handle AJAX cases where you do not need a form. I was trying to find a way of doing the same straight to PHP, without a form, and without AJAX. It oviously does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You *can't* make a browser send data to the server with only PHP and a HTML button. You have to make either a link that looks like a button, use JavaScript (AJAX), or enclose the button in a form.

Comment: makes me wonder why he wants to use a button instead of just a regular link with parameters

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Joni, but Fabi, no need to wonder. The situation I am dealing with requires me NOT using links, that simple :)